# Android out of memory error?

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I keep getting these errors while retreiving images here.

```
07-26 17:21:29.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(396): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
 07-26 17:21:29.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(396):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
   07-26 17:21:29.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(396):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
    07-26 17:21:29.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(396):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
     07-26 17:21:29.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(396):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
      07-26 17:21:29.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(396):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
       07-26 17:21:29.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(396):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
     07-26 17:21:29.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(396):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
      07-26 17:21:29.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(396):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
     07-26 17:21:29.194: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(396): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

It occurs here when i try to retreive the images with this code.

public void getImages() throws IOException{

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("https://sites.google.com/site/theitrangers/images/webImages.txt");
    HttpResponse response;

        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


            HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();

            BufferedHttpEntity buf = new BufferedHttpEntity(ht);

            InputStream is = buf.getContent();


            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line + "\n");

              imageUrl = total.toString();
              Log.v("getImage1", "Retreived image");
            }
     }
```

Comment: Please search for similar threads. There are lots of them.

Comment: They arent specific to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it's because you're using BufferedHttpEntity it tries to load whole response to memory. Did you tried without it?

```
InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
```

and then process it?

Comment: If i remove it then it will cause syntax in other places where its called below.

Comment: What do you mean by syntax? You're using that BufferedHttpEntity somewhere else? I'm not sure if you'll jump through it with that buffered entity actually. Check implementation: http://goo.gl/41MEV. It creates byte array with content in constructor so sooner or later with big image you'll get OOM exception anyways.

Comment: Wow..So i mean i know there has to be a more effecient way to do this.

Comment: Read my comment below on the last answer

Comment: How big is that file with urls?

Comment: each text document is  4 KB and its 4 text documents with URLS. So that's a total of 16 KB.

Comment: It looks like this code is pretty much cutted out so i'm not sure about this all :] You may try das_weezul clue... I think what he mean is that you do: "imageUrl = total.toString()" assignment in while loop, maybe try it outside of it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are intending to do this, but you are appending each line of URLs(?) from the text file you read in to the StringBuffer and then you assign the urls read up till now to imageUrl. That means you are basically doing this:

```
imageUrl = URL1
imageUrl = URL1, URL2
...
imageUrl = URL1, URL2, ... URLn
```

Maybe that is causing the memory issue.

Comment: Right so what im doing is... i have text files on my website. I have the app fetch the text docs read the urls from them, and then set them as a variable... Now the reason im using a text document is because the url changes, and this will be the only way i could update the application to change urls.

Comment: Yes but what you are doing is, you keep on assigning the intermediate lines while looping over the lines of the buffer. So you assign URl1, in the next loop you assign URL1, URL2 ... Why don't you just read in the lines into the buffer and assign it at the end?

Comment: Could you give me an example from my code above, in reference to what your saying? Or do you need the code where i read the text documents to get the URLs?

Comment: Could you give an example of what your saying in your comment?